# Execute Commands after print window is closed

Tags: javascript, jquery, events, event-handling, jquery-events

I'm printing a web page using the code below:

```
window.print();
```

I want to execute a few commands after the Print dialog is closed. How can I detect it?

Comment: It is enough to explain what you want to do, let other users give you more and any suggestion they may have. (Personally, I do not think you can use events from Print dialog, maybe to open new window, than print, than close and detect that).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
window.onload = PrintMe;

function PrintMe() {
    window.print();

    alert("Closed Printing");


}
```

Comment: this is going to work only if the browser provides a synchronous print() method.